# Change background of child if parent :hover

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I want to change the bg-color of `.circle.icon` if `posts-item` is hovered. Any idea how to accomplish that, possibly without Javascript?

```
<div id="scr1" class="large-6 columns timeline">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <ul class="posts">
        <li class="posts-item">
            <div class="circle icon"></div>
             <h2 class="posts-item-title">
                 <a href=""></a>
              </h2>
            <p class="summary"></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like so.

```
.posts-item:hover .circle.icon {
    background: green;
}
```

No jQuery - Everyone's happy :)

Comment: Thanks so much, I just got stucked and wrote the most stupid selectors of all time. Thanks again man.